# AJAX within AJAX not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, facebook

Like Facebook commenting system, when you comment, your comment gets appended to the previous comments and is displayed at once. That's what I am trying to achieve here. Though the comment get appended but one will have to reload the page before it shows up.

**Note:** Each post are loaded with just two comments and a button that will allow you load more is then attached. When you click on the button, it loads the remaining comments via AJAX and changes the `More comments` button with `Less comments` which reduces the comment to two when clicked.

If a comment, I want it to work like that of Facebook and at the same time if the user has not click on the `More comments` button it should automatically show the remaining comments with the new one the user just commented.

**The HTML :**

```
<div class='feeds'>
<div class='post'>
<h5> Post Header </h5>
<p> post 1 2 3 </p>
<a href ='#' class = 'comment'>Comment</a>
<div class='comments'>
    <div class='comment_data>
      <div class = ' per_comment '>
        <p> Comment 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class = 'per_comment '>
        <p> Comment 2</p>
      </div>
        <button class='morecomments ' value='7' type='submit '>
        More comments</button>
        <div class = 'commentdiv'>
            <textarea autocomplete = 'off' class='commenttext form-control' rows = '1' placeholder='Have your say...'></textarea>
            <button class='comment btn btn-xs btn-primary onespacedown' value = '7' type='submit'>Comment</button>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- end of comment_data div -->
</div> <!-- end of post div -->
```

---

**And this the AJAX :**

```
$('.feeds').on('click', '.comment', function () {
var $this = $(this);
var post_comment = $this.parents('.feeds').find('.commenttext').val();
var post_id = $(this).val();
var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
var request = $.ajax({
      url: "insertcomment.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { post : post_id , user : user_id, comment: post_comment },
      dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function( msg ) {    
        var $pc = $this.parents('.feeds').find('.comment_data');
        var $button = $this.prev('.pullcomments');
        //if the comments are already loaded then don't load it again just display it
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "comments.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    post: post_id,
                    user: user_id
                },
                dataType: "html"
            });
            request.done(function (msg1) {
                html(msg1).appendTo($pc);
                $button.slideDown();
                $this.replaceWith("<button class='lesscomments pullcomments' value='7' name = 'more' type='submit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span></button>"); 
                $this.parents('.feeds').find('.commenttext').val('');
        });
    });
 })
```

---

Comment: Ugh. Nested functions.  Move your second ajax call to a function, and call that function within your `request.done` event (rather than having all that code *within* the `request.done` event).

Comment: Which part of your code doesn't work?

Comment: @Jivings I said it appended but doesn't show the comment until you refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

```
html(msg1).appendTo($pc);
```

**To this, if the ajax call returns just the newly added comment:**

```
$pc.prepend(msg1);
```

This will put the returned html after the last "per_comment" element, if there is one. Otherwise, it will put it as the first child of the "comment_data" element.

**To this, if the ajax call returns all the comments:**

```
$pc.children('.per_comment').remove();
$pc.prepend(msg1);
```

This removes the list of comments and then inserts the new list returned by the ajax call.

EDIT: I see that you display the comments in descending order, so I assume you want the new comment at the top.

Comment: This is working but the existing comments are displaying twice each while the last(the one I just commented) is once...

Comment: What html is the ajax call returning? Is it returning all three comments or just the new one that was just added?

Comment: The first two are not return. So one or more are returned with `SQL: LIMIT 2, 1000`

Comment: There is no way the code I showed above will cause the original two comments to get duplicated -- _unless they are returned by the ajax call_. You need to verify what is being returned by the ajax call. Try the second set of lines above and see what is displayed.

Comment: This first two are loaded with SQL statement `LIMIT 0, 3` and the remaining is loaded with via AJAX `LIMIT 2, 100`. And that's the AJAX within the AJAX.

Comment: You should verify what is being returned by the ajax call. You could simply add `alert(msg1);`.

Comment: @user3009875 - LIMIT 2, 100 does not seem right to me if the rows are sorted by time in descending order. I would think LIMIT 0, 1 would return the most recently added row. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BSsNX/2/) that might give you some ideas on how this could work.

Answer (score 0):

due to Javascript binding, you are overwriting the request variable, so it will probably behave funny. Try something like this:

```
$('.feeds').on('click', '.comment', function () {
var $this = $(this);
var post_comment = $this.parents('.feeds').find('.commenttext').val();
var post_id = $(this).val();
var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
var request = $.ajax({
      url: "insertcomment.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { post : post_id , user : user_id, comment: post_comment },
      dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function( msg ) {    
        var $pc = $this.parents('.feeds').find('.comment_data');
        var $button = $this.prev('.pullcomments');
        //if the comments are already loaded then don't load it again just display it
            var request2 = $.ajax({
                url: "comments.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    post: post_id,
                    user: user_id
                },
                dataType: "html"
            });
            request2.done(function (msg1) {
                html(msg1).appendTo($pc);
                $button.slideDown();
                $this.replaceWith("<button class='lesscomments pullcomments' value='7' name = 'more' type='submit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span></button>"); 
                $this.parents('.feeds').find('.commenttext').val('');
        });
    });
 })
```

Comment: Finding it hard to spot the changes you've made to the one I posted to make it work...

Comment: I just changed request to request2 for the second ajax request.

Comment: Still the same, it gets appended but it doesn't show until page refresh.